# Handle Vercel 413 error for SvelteKit server form actions

Tags: svelte, serverless, vercel, sveltekit

I have a form that takes in an image file. The form is submitted via the `actions` property in the `form` tag. Following is the code for the form tag

```html
<form
    id="createMintForm"
    method="post"
    action="?/createMint"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    on:submit={() => {
        isLoading = true;
        return true;
    }}
    on:error={(e)=>{
        console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(e);
        alert(e)
    }}
    use:enhance
>
```

I tried adding the `on:error` function to the form but it isn't working. The error sent by vercel is the following `{"error": {"code": "413", "message": "Request Entity Too Large"}}`

The action `createMint` is in a `+page.server.ts` file and the file is uploaded to Supabase.

How can I handle this error on the client side and show an alert dialog to the user?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Vercel error, it sounds like it is happening on load. You should be able to use the [SvelteKit `+error` route](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error) to catch and display this error.

```html
// +error.svelte

<script lang="ts">
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>

<h1>{$page.status}: {$page.error.message}</h1>
```

You can optionally place this file in `/src/routes` to catch all errors, or in your route directory to catch errors only on that route.